# Put MySQL request result in table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table

```
<?PHP
?>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="one.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<?
include_once "db.php";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type='weddingdressaline' ORDER BY user_id"); 
{
    echo "<table width='100%' border='5' bordercolor='#860071' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='5'>";
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<tr>";
            $i = 0;
            while ($i < 3)
            {
                echo '<td><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" BGCOLOR="#AA99C5"><TR><TD><div class="container"><A HREF="viewproduct.php?user_id=' . $row["user_id"] . '"><img src="showimage.php?user_id=' . $row["user_id"] . '" ALIGN="CENTER" /></A></div></td><tr><td><CENTER><STRONG>' . $row['price'] . '</STRONG></td></TABLE>';
                $i++;
            }
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    } else {
        echo "<tr><td colspan='" . ($i + 1) . "'>No Results found!</td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} 
?>
```

The code is suppose to put one item into one column. Unfortunately its placing one result for the entire row. If anyone has any ideas how to fix this please help.

Comment: "problwm"...it doesnt let you use "problem" for a reason, don't skirt the rules

Comment: The `while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { ... }` part is executed for every item. Furthermore, the `while ($i < 3) { ... }` part within is responsible for duplicating that item 3 times. Thus, there lies your problem.

Comment: Wow, capital tags and attributes. Just had a flashback to 1999.

Comment: Not to mention they're not all getting closed, a table inside a table, and deprecated elements/attributes... Oh my!

Answer (score 1):

You have some access brackets in your code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type='weddingdressaline' ORDER BY user_id"); 
{ <===
    echo "<table width='100%' border='5' bordercolor='#860071' cellspacing='5' cellpadding='5'>";
     [....]
    echo "</table>";
} <===
```

Comment: I'm not getting this comment: the PHP interpreter doesn't care about additional brackets, right?

Comment: Its still an ugly way to code, not to mention highly confusing. Whether it works or not.

Comment: @pthurmond true, I was just wondering if it meant more than just that.

Comment: @Legolas: Doesn't it modify the current scope?

Answer (score 0):

First of all please learn some clean coding standards for everyones sake:
http://drupal.org/coding-standards

The second problem is that your are outputting this in the wrong. Trying to use tables for one (use divs) is just poor markup these days. All your styles should be in your CSS, not embedded on the page.

Here is your greatly improved markup. You use CSS to change how it is displayed on the page, not a table structure.

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="one.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<?php
include_once "db.php";

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type = 'weddingdressaline' ORDER BY user_id");

echo '<div class="productTable">';

if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo '
      <div class="container">
        <div class="productImage">
          <a href="viewproduct.php?user_id=' . $row->user_id . '">
            <img src="showimage.php?user_id=' . $row->user_id . '" align="center" />
          </a>
        </div>
        <div class="price">' . $row->price . '</div>
      </div>';
  }
}
else {    
  echo '<div class="container"><div class="noResults">No Results found!</div></div>';
}

echo "</div>";
?>
</body>
</html>
```